# Get some trounble when using drawBuffers in WebGL2

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, webgl2

I want to combine my deferred renderer and forward renderer together. In order to share the same depth buffer, I use a single frame buffer object with 4 color attachments, COLOR_ATTACHMENT0-2 for G-buffer rendering, COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 for deferred shading and forward rendering, here's the pesudo code:

```
//**Gbufffer part**
Bind G-Buffer FBO
gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2]);
draw the G buffer

//**Lighting part**
Bind Lighting buffer FBO

//**Shading part**
Bind G-Buffer FBO
gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3]);

//**Forward rendring part**
//Still use the G-Buffer FBO and COLOR_ATTACHMENT3
draw forward material
```

when using this, I got a mistake in firefox:

**Error: WebGL: drawBuffers: `buffers[i]` must be NONE or COLOR_ATTACHMENTi.**

when lauching in Chrome, I got this:

**FrameBufferObject.ts:151 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawBuffers: COLOR_ATTACHMENTi_EXT or NONE**

What's wrong with my code? This really confuse me...THX.

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly you must use color attachment 0 for the first buffer, color attachment 1 for the second, color attachment 2 for the 3rd etc..

In otherwords this is ok

```
gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // color attachment 0 to draw buffer 0
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,  // color attachment 1 to draw buffer 1
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,  // color attachment 2 to draw buffer 2
]);
```

This is also ok

```
gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // color attachment 0 to draw buffer 0
  gl.NONE,               // NONE to draw buffer 1
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,  // color attachment 2 to draw buffer 2
]);
```

This is not!!

```
gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // color attachment 0 to draw buffer 0
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,  // color attachment 2 to draw buffer 1 ERROR!
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,  // color attachment 1 to draw buffer 2 ERROR!
]);
```

So in your case.

```
gl.drawBuffers([
   gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3,  // color attachment 3 to draw buffer 0 ERROR!
]);
```

The must always match 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc.

If that's really what you're doing you should make 3 framebuffer objects. One with the first 3 buffers, one with the 4th buffer, and one with all 4 buffers. Then you'd do something like

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, threeAttachmentFB);
gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2]);

.. draw stuff ..

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, oneAttachmentFB);
gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0]);

.. draw stuff ..

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fourAttachmentFB);
gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,
                gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3]);

.. draw stuff ..
```

In edition to that, various combos are not guaranteed to work. It's unclear what the limits are in WebGL2 but in WebGL1 only these combinations are guaranteed to work

- one color attachment (with or without depth or depth_stencil)

  ```
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  ```
- two color attachments (with or without depth or depth_stencil)

  ```
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  ```
- three color attachments (with or without depth or depth_stencil)

  ```
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  ```
- four color attachments (with or without depth or depth_stencil)

  ```
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT1_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT2_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  COLOR_ATTACHMENT3_WEBGL = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE
  ```

All other combinations may or may not work depending on the GPU/Driver/Browser/OS

Comment: "If you remember correctly" ... I think you do, seeing how that is exactly the validation performed by the source fragment I posted :) +1 for adding clear and practical samples of what *is* and *isn't* ok.

Comment: Oh, even more +1 for pointing out the actual `gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3]);` bug in the sample code.

Comment: THX a lot, does that mean if I code like this:gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // color attachment 0 to draw buffer 0
  gl.NONE,               // NONE to draw buffer 1
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,  // color attachment 2 to draw buffer 2
]);  I would just draw the color_attachment0 and 2, and keep attachment1?

Answer (score 1):

I would not be surprised if your actual code is slightly different from what you are posting here.

Take a look at the Firefox sources for *WebGLContext::DrawBuffers* over at https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/canvas/WebGLContextFramebufferOperations.cpp:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < buffers.Length(); i++) {
    // "If the GL is bound to a draw framebuffer object, the `i`th buffer listed in
    //  bufs must be COLOR_ATTACHMENTi or NONE. Specifying a buffer out of order,
    //  BACK, or COLOR_ATTACHMENTm where `m` is greater than or equal to the value of
    // MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS, will generate the error INVALID_OPERATION.

    // WEBGL_draw_buffers:
    // "The value of the MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_WEBGL parameter must be greater than or
    //  equal to that of the MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS_WEBGL parameter."
    // This means that if buffers.Length() isn't larger than MaxDrawBuffers, it won't
    // be larger than MaxColorAttachments.
    if (buffers[i] != LOCAL_GL_NONE &&
        buffers[i] != LOCAL_GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i)
    {
        ErrorInvalidOperation("%s: `buffers[i]` must be NONE or COLOR_ATTACHMENTi.",
                              funcName);
        return;
    }
}
```

Your code is failing that check. Maybe you've got the order mixed up?

**[Edit]** As gman points out, your second call to drawbuffers, `gl.drawBuffers([gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3]);`, doesn't comply with this validation **[/Edit]**